# how to get the range of the price using range in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

i have a table with the following structure.

[image: Table Image]

From that table i need to find the price using the range that was given in the table.

```
ex:
   if i give the Footage_Range1=100 means it will give the output as 0.00 and 
   if Footage_Range1=101 means the output is 2.66
   if Footage_Range1=498 means the output is 2.66
```

How to write the query to get the price?

Comment: where is the table structure and how is the output calculated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i understood your requirements correctly you can try this:

```
SELECT
    price 
FROM 
    my_table
WHERE
    Footage_Range1 <= YOUR_RANGE
ORDER BY
    Footage_Range1 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Where `YOUR_RANGE` is the input : 100,101,498 etc

Basically this query will return the closest price to the `Footage_Range1` input that is smaller or equal.

Comment: hi @stephen i have tried ur code but if i give the query "SELECT price FROM [Footage_price] WHERE Footage_Range1 <= 1250 and mfg_id=2
ORDER BY Footage_Range1 DESC" means it will not give the exact output. it shows the result as ,0.00
2.66
2.34
2.21
2.11
2.06

Comment: @JasperManickaraj you forgot the `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Limit 1 is not valid in sql. so i put this query "SELECT top 1* FROM [Footage_price] WHERE Footage_Range1 <= 1250 and mfg_id=2
ORDER BY Footage_Range1 DESC" but this also returns a row value of Footage_Range=800

Comment: it should return you the price : 2.06 since `Footage_Range1 <= 1250`... so it returns you one row or 2 rows?

Comment: `TOP 1` should return you just 1 row

Comment: but it returns the price 2.11 who's footage_range1 is 800

Comment: sorry @Stephan here the Footage_Range1 datatype is nvarchar. i change it to int and it works..

Comment: @JasperManickaraj good :) because i couldn't figure out why it wasn't working out for you :D

Comment: @JasperManickaraj glad i could help, don't forget to accept the answer you think its right so that other users may see it. cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

I have the sample for your requirement. Please take a look.

```
DECLARE @range INT = 498
DECLARE @Test TABLE(mfg_id INT, footage_range INT, price FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @Test ( mfg_id, footage_range, price )
            SELECT 2, 0, 0.00
UNION ALL   SELECT 2, 101, 2.66
UNION ALL   SELECT 2, 500, 2.34
UNION ALL   SELECT 2, 641, 2.21
UNION ALL   SELECT 2, 800, 2.11
UNION ALL   SELECT 2, 1250, 2.06

SELECT TOP 1 
 * 
FROM @Test WHERE footage_range <= @range
ORDER BY footage_range DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try below code..

select price from your_table where footage_range1 <=rangevalue limit 1;
```

Comment: This will return more than one value.

Comment: Oops...yeah @L_Holcombe u r right :) will modify my post. Thanks

Comment: @SeeSharp the `ORDER BY` here is crucial in order to get the closest price where the range input is smaller or equal then `Footage_Range1`